# Why Jquery Print Array elements different almost every time?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, api

So I have written an algorithm wherein a loop I have been hitting an API URL and Getting the value in another function. so that another function when I am consoling data it shows different almost every time.

Example:

```
function LoadManageJobs(data){
  console.log(data);
 for(index=0;index<data.results.length;index++){
  if(!data.results[index].job_area){
  data.results[index].job_area = "Unknown";
  }
  if(data.results[index].application_deadline){
                    var dateString = data.results[index].application_deadline;
                    var momentObj = moment(dateString, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
                    dateMomentString = momentObj.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
                }
  else{
    dateMomentString = "";
  }
  ******var JobId = data.results[index].job_id;
  var ApplicantsUrl = '/api/application/list/'+JobId+'/';
  get(ApplicantsUrl,LoadApplicants);******

 

   $('#manage_jobs').append('<tr class="job-items">'+
                        '<td class="title">'+
                          '<h5><a href="'+'/job-detail/'+data.results[index].slug+'">'+data.results[index].title+'</a></h5>'+
                          '<div class="info">'+
                            '<span class="office-location"><a><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-map-pin"><path d="M21 10c0 7-9 13-9 13s-9-6-9-13a9 9 0 0 1 18 0z"></path><circle cx="12" cy="10" r="3"></circle></svg>'+data.results[index].job_area+'</a></span>'+
                            '<span class="job-type full-time"><a><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-clock"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><polyline points="12 6 12 12 16 14"></polyline></svg>'+data.results[index].job_type+'</a></span>'+
                          '</div>'+
                        '</td>'+
                        '<td class="application"><a class="count'+index+'"></a></td>'+
                        '<td class="deadline">'+dateMomentString+'</td>'+
                        '<td class="status active">Active</td>'+
                        '<td class="action">'+
                        '<a class="preview" title="Preview"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-eye"><path d="M1 12s4-8 11-8 11 8 11 8-4 8-11 8-11-8-11-8z"></path><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="3"></circle></svg></a>'+
                        '<a class="edit" title="Edit"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-edit"><path d="M20 14.66V20a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h5.34"></path><polygon points="18 2 22 6 12 16 8 16 8 12 18 2"></polygon></svg></a>'+
                        '</td>'+
                        '</tr>');
                  
 }
}
```

You can see in top star *** section where I have been hitting an api for geeting value.

```
  var arr = [];
       function LoadApplicants(data){   
          arr.push(data);
          //JSON.stringify(arr);
          for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){           
          $('.count'+i+'').html(arr[i].count+" Application(s)");
        
   }
          console.log(arr);
       }
```

So I have been getting value in this function. But the problem is when I am printing these values the index of the value is always changing. Why this is happening. Please Help me out.

Comment: Need to explain issue in more detail. Really not clear what specific problem is or which index is causing problems since you have multiple loops

Answer (score 0):

I recommend breaking apart the API call from the display of the resulting data. Right now that's all combined in your "get()" call. To diagnose:

1. Call the API, log the results
2. Now pass the results through to the display method

The push() method will push in exact order what you want, so compare #1 vs #2. That should help you understand the difference.